# Using facebook api doc for excluding placements from ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey everyone I am trying to use facebook api to retreive placements used for specific ads.
I used insights endpoint with the breakdown option.
Now I am trying to update an ad so I can remove a placement used.
I cannot find any info in the doc, anyone can help me ?